# How to read /dev/input/eventX in android? Is this only possible using JNI or we can use java only?

Tags: android, input, low-level

My device is rooted. I'm getting events through adb. But dn't know how to fetch same continuous stream of events in android application. Below bunch of code ask prompt for SuperUser permission but dnt fetch anything.

```
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
     DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
     os.writeBytes("chmod a=rw /dev/input/event2" + "\n");
     os.flush();
     os.writeBytes("exit\n");
     os.flush();

     process.getOutputStream().
     final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
     int read;
     final char[] buffer = new char[4096];
     while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, read);
           tv.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
           }
          reader.close();

        // Waits for the command to finish.
          process.waitFor();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to feed `su` some commands on its stdin or something?  Why not just `su -c 'command1; command2'`.

Or do you think that `.exec("su")` is going to raise the privileges of the current process?  That's not how it works.

When you `su` or `sudo` from the command line, the process tree looks like this:

```
bash───sudo───bash
```

(from `pstree -s $$` to show the parents of the current shell).

So although you get a root prompt in the same terminal, you're actually running a different shell, after your non-root shell forks + execs `su`.

---

So if `.exec("su");` doesn't fork first, you're replacing your current process by [`execve()`ing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) `su` in place of your process.  I don't know those Java functions, but that might explain getting no output: the function call never returns and your process is replaced with `su` with no args.

Oh, nvm that theory, I checked the docs and [`.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) does run the command in a new process.  So it's more like POSIX `system()` than POSIX `exec()`.  Still, it runs a new process and doesn't give your current process root privileges.  I also don't know why you're printing `chmod\n` to stdout.

Comment: I want root privilege to execute command:- chmod a=rw /dev/input/event2.  instead of chmod. So that i can read input events under /dev/input/event2 which is touchscreen event for my device.I'm writing this command on output stream of process having root access in hope that this command executes as root. Please tell me where i'm wrong. And is reading /dev/input/event2 possible through java code?

Comment: @HimanshuGangwar: Use `su -c 'chmod a=rw /dev/input/event2'` instead of trying to pipe commands to `su`.  You're doing that wrong anyway, writing to its output instead of input.